# Sync Chromium without google account

Tags: sync, chromium

I admit it, i'm a bit paranoid..

I have come to like firefox sync together with my own sync server. Now for various reasons, I'm tempted to use Chromium (or Iron) instead. Now is there a way to have bookmarks, passwords etc. synchronised without pushing the data to google? WebDAV or something like it would be perfect.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a [corresponding chromium bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=181429).

You can set up your own chromium sync server and launch the browser using

```
--sync-url="<your server here>"
```

Answer (score 2):

Your bookmarks are very likely stored in the file:

```
~/.config/chromium/Default/Bookmarks
```

You can check the exact location by opening

```
chrome://version/
```

in the browser. Put the above file in version control, and your done ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try a DVCS such as git or bzr or mercurial.  Everything you want to sync is a text file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try Xmarks, which I believe allows you to use your own server if you wanted.

Answer (score -3):

You could use a backup/syncing tool or service such as Dropbox to monitor your Chromium user profile folder on two or more different computers.

For more information about the location of the user profile folders or how to change its location, refer to http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory