# How to set up a own Chrome sync server?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, sync, python

I'm trying to set up a sync server for Chromium/Chrome, but i'm totally failed. I also couldn't find a How-To ([like this here for Firefox](http://docs.services.mozilla.com/howtos/run-sync.html)) for that.

I only found [this question from '10 on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/169648/sync-chromium-without-google-account) and [a corresponding chromium bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=181429) which says that the command line flag `--sync-url="<your server here>"` is required.

Could someone help me and give me the exact instructions what I need to do to set up the sync server on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 6):

Use [this](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/sync/tools/testserver/chromiumsync.py&q=chromiumsync.py&sq=package:chromium) python file to run a chromium  sync server. (taken from the blog post) Several other files to test it are in there as well. Get the server running and point your '--sync-url=""' option to it.

Answer (score 5):

There is now a repository that has a sync server written in python.

https://github.com/coseltech/chrome-sync-server

I have pointed to a fork as it has more recent changes for new versions of chromium

should be as simple as:

`python sync_server.py --port=8090`

Here's some more details on the sync protocol too:

http://damianblog.com/2014/02/09/inside-chrome-sync/